# How I place an Image in Tab Activity TABS in android?

Tags: android, android-tabactivity

I want to Place an Image instead of an Text which is Shown in return Statement

```
  @Override
            public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        return "Personal Information";
                    case 1:
                        return "Address Infromation";
                    case 2:
                        return "Qualification";
                    case 3:
                        return "Work Experience";
                }
                return null;
            }
```

Comment: https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-tablayout-example-using-viewpager-fragments/

Comment: I want to know how we place an image instead of Text

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `setIcon()` in the place of string like,

```
tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setIcon(R.id.ic_tab_contacts);
```

in your case method might look like,

```
@Override
            public int getPageTitle(int position) {

                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        return R.id.ic_tab_contacts;
                    case 1:
                        return R.id.ic_tab_profile;
                    case 2:
                        return R.id.ic_tab_Call;
                    case 3:
                        return R.id.ic_tab_message;
                }
                return null;
            }
```